# Is it possible to save program data in RAM even when the program is closed?

Tags: c++, pointers, persistence, storage, ram

Essentially what I'm wondering is if I wanted to persist data in RAM between program executions; as in could I store information in RAM after the program finishes if I write down where in RAM I'm going to save it. Could I do something like so:

```
int *p = 10;
send_to_database(p); // Send the location in memory to some server
p = null_ptr;
del p;

The program finishes running

The program starts running again
int *p;
p = get_from_db(user_token);
```

I suppose what I'm really wondering is could I intentionally leak memory but come back to it later? It wouldn't get taken care of by any type of garbage collection because we would simply forget about the location of it for now. Then the next time I run the program I look up where I stored something in RAM and load it back in.

Just so no one is horrified, this is a purely theoretical question. It just occurred to me that you could do some kind of really funky user authentication with this where it only persists their login as long as the computer is not shut off. Since the auth token would get saved to a different location on everyone's computer it strikes me that it would be difficult to rummage up the location of the auth token when the program is closed.

Comment: Wouldn't all allocated memory (including leaked memory) be cleared by the operating system after the program closes? Please note that I am not sure of this, but this is what I saw with my own memory leaks (Visual Studio + Windows 7)

Comment: @DrDonut I think that potentially when VS is running things it keeps track of memory being used a lot better than an OS normally would. Though I could be totally making that up. I'm not sure if newer OSs sandbox every program or if they will let you write to any available memory.

Comment: This could be, I don't know. For your other point: Once I tried to let one program write to the memory space of another program as a means of sharing data, this used gcc and Windows xp. I couldn't get this to work back then, but take a look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-sharedmemory-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that we're talking about your average everyday computer: no, this is impossible.

First of all, your program is allocating memory from the C++ memory manager, which in turn allocates memory from the operating system.
When a process exits, the operating system reclaims any memory the process was using.

Further, the memory your program is allocating resides in *virtual* memory - every process has its own, identical, address space.
This is mapped to locations in physical memory by the operating system and the hardware.
In fact, there's not even any guarantee that an address in your program will map to the same physical RAM location every time you access it during the same execution.

Besides, it would be trivial(ish) for an attacker to figure out where the token is.
(Figuring out a way left as an exercise.)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. The memory of a process is wiped away when the process exists, and when a new one starts, it starts from scratch. Else you would have a major security issue.

What you want to do then, is to store what p points to. When you restart, you malloc() the same size, and read back from your storage the content. Beware that you can not store pointers on disk and expect them do be valid when loading them back in a new session.